# Why does exporting as default from another node module result in an undefined object when compiled with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules

I'm using a node module called `demux-postgres`, which relies on `massive`. Due to version issues between `massive` and `pg-promise`, they recommend using the export of massive they have provided by calling `const { massive } = require("demux-postgres")` instead of `const { massive } = require("massive")`

`massive` is undefined when using the former `require`, this appears to be because the generated JavaScript in `index.js` is attempting to export `massive_1.default`.

[image]

If I remove the `.default` everything works correctly.

[image]

The source for `index.js` can be found here: https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js-postgres/blob/develop/src/index.ts. I've forked the repo myself & loaded the project into VS Code, intellisense correctly shows `massive` being exported as a default with the function.

[image]

Unfortunately I'm [not getting much traction](https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js-postgres/issues/78) from the repo itself, and my knowledge of TypeScript is quite limited, which is why I've posted here :).

Comment: Seems like `demux-postgres` have a bug. I have a raised a PR for the same here: 
https://github.com/EOSIO/demux-js-postgres/pull/83

Comment: Awesome, could you explain the comment a bit for me, just for my knowledge :)?

Comment: What would be better is if you could provide an answer in here with how you fixed it :), I can then mark it.